# A finite ring without zero divisors has a neutral element for the multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-rings

> $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a finite ring  without zero divisors. Prove that $R$ has a neutral element for the multiplication.

Can someone give a hint or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Fix $r\in R$, $r\neq 0$, and define $f:R\to R$ as $f(x)=rx$. Use the finite property and the fact that $R$ has no zero divisors to find an element $e\in R$ such that $r\cdot e=r$ (remember that every function $g\in A^A$ is surjective iff it's injective, when $A$ is finite).

Then try to prove that $a$ is actually your identity.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the hint. I've this now: If $r$ is not $0$ then $f $ is injective. Because if $rx=ry$ for some $x,y \in R$ than is $x=y$ because $R$ has no zero divisors. Because f is injective there is a $x \in R$ such that $rx=r$, so $x$ is a neutral element for the multiplication. Correct?

Comment: Almost. There's a big step you need to justify. Indeed, $rx=r$, now you need to show that $ax=a$ **for all** $a\in R$.